# GitFlow, should my release branch include minor version number?

Tags: design, git, gitflow, semantic-versioning

I've found it difficult to find a definitive answer to this question. Using **Semantic Versioning** and **GitFlow** should my release branch include the minor version number? I'm **not** referring to tags.

My application tags looks like this:

```
v1.9.1
v1.9.2
v1.9.3
```

I'm now ready to do a **release candidate**. Should my **release branch** in git be named `v1.9-RC` or `v1.9.3-RC`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are confusing Minor version and Patch version.
From http://semver.org/ :

> Given a version number MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH, increment the:
>
> MAJOR version when you make incompatible API changes,
> MINOR version when you add functionality in a backwards-compatible manner, and
> PATCH version when you make backwards-compatible bug fixes.

This leads to the following "rule":

- A **Release** branch should contain the MAJOR and the MINOR number (e.g. release/1.9)
- A **Hotfix** branch (which contains bugfixes) should also contain the PATCH number (e.g. hotfix/1.9.1).

As a side note, there is no "right" or "wrong" and semantic versioning has no knowledge of your git workflow, so in the end the only thing that matters is that you and your team can work with it.

Comment: fwiw, I also see the case of a *bugfix-only* release, whose branch I'm naming `release-x.y.Z`. It's different from a *hotfix* release in that `release-x.y.Z` branches off from `develop` rather than from `master`. afaik, SemVer PATCH versions are bugfix-only versios (which includes hotfixes). (this confused me a bit, and led me to this question.)